How to GROUP_CONCAT row values, but break groups by an arbitrary "gap" flag?
Let's say I have an existing SQL table (which I am given, I have no control over it) describing a list of connections between cities, with a column flagging any gaps. Here's a simplified example:



PATH_ID
PATH_SEQ
FROM_CITY
TO_CITY
GAP




1
1
Seattle
Portland
NULL


1
2
Portland
San Francisco
NULL


1
3
San Francisco
Los Angeles
NULL


1
4
Los Angeles
NULL
NULL


2
1
Dallas
Tulsa
NULL


2
2
Tulsa
Springfield
NULL


2
3
Springfield
Chicago
NULL


2
4
Chicago
Detroit
Y


2
5
Detroit
Pittsburgh
NULL


2
6
Pittsburgh
Philadelphia
NULL


2
7
Philadelphia
NULL
NULL



... and so on. I can use GROUP_CONCAT to build a comma separated list of paths ordered by PATH_SEQ:
SELECT
    PATH_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(FROM_CITY ORDER BY PATH_SEQ) AS CITIES
FROM table
GROUP BY PATH_ID

...results in:



PATH_ID
CITIES




1
Seattle,Portland,San Francisco,Los Angeles


2
Dallas,Tulsa,Springfield,Chicago,Detroit,Pittsburgh,Philadelphia



Great! It feels like I'm almost there. But there should be no "connection" between Chicago and Detroit, indicated by that "GAP" column. What I really want is to somehow respect the GAP flag and use that to split into some kind of a sub-path. Ideal query result:



PATH_ID
SUBPATH_ID
CITIES




1
1
Seattle,Portland,San Francisco,Los Angeles


2
1
Dallas,Tulsa,Springfield,Chicago


2
2
Detroit,Pittsburgh,Philadelphia



The "SUBPATH_ID" could be anything. It doesn't need to be a number or even ordered. It doesn't even need to exist, for instance this would be fine, too:



PATH_ID
CITIES




1
Seattle,Portland,San Francisco,Los Angeles


2
Dallas,Tulsa,Springfield,Chicago


2
Detroit,Pittsburgh,Philadelphia



I just need a separate row to distinguish between the path starting at Dallas and the one starting at Detroit, while preserving the original PATH_ID. I feel like I have to maybe create a temporary table and generate these SUBPATH_IDs first to distinguish them, and then do the GROUP_CONCAT query using that, but I'm at the limit of my SQL knowledge unfortunately. Any tips or hints?
SQL engine is sqlite, if that makes a difference.

This is an example of Gaps-and-Islands. You can use a running COUNT() on the GAP column (counts the number of non-nulls) to get a grouping ID, then group by that column
SELECT
    t.PATH_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.FROM_CITY ORDER BY t.PATH_SEQ) AS CITIES
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
      COUNT(t.GAP) OVER (PARTITION BY t.PATH_ID ORDER BY t.PATH_SEQ ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS GapCount
    FROM YourTable AS t
) AS t
GROUP BY
  t.PATH_ID,
  t.GapCount;

db-fiddle.com

Awesome. Sometimes all you need is the right keyword to search for. "Gaps-and-Islands" gets me going in the right direction. Thanks a lot!
